# Translation for Date/Time Strings based on Locale (Android)

Tags: android, datetime, date, translation

I was wondering if anyone knew of a built in way to translate certain date/time words based on the users locale?

Specifically works like Day, hour? I know that Android will translate months of the year, and the am/pm strings using a specified locale via SimpleDateFormat but I was wondering if any of these other strings were available?

Specially we are looking to show recent dates and times using the format: "x hours ago" and it would be nice if that string could be translated based on locale.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Android Localization.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: Hi Dan, not really what we were looking for. I was trying to see if these translations were built into the DateTime stuff in any way. In the same way that the Months and AM/PM are. Thanks though.

Comment: Oh, as far as I know Java doesn't have a build-in translation. Good luck though.